# Merging SAS Datasets - Only 1 Variable

Tags: sas, dataset

Scenario: I need to merge two SAS datasets together into one and maintain any non-matching values.

DatasetA contains: CustomerID, HouseholdID, EmailAddress, etc.
DatasetB contains: HouseholdID

```
DatasetA:
CustomerID     HouseholdID   EmailAddress  ...
1001            100001         joe@aol.com
1002            100002         john@gmail.com 
2003            100003         sally@comcast.net

DatasetB:
HouseholdID
100003 
100001
```

I want to merge these two together, but obviously if I do that as is, I'll lose track of DatasetB.

To expand, DatasetA contains ALL customer information, and DatasetB only contains certain HouseholdID's (not all of them). I want to create a table that looks like this by merging. So, I think I need to duplicate HouseholdID in DatasetB, but how can I do this?

```
Desired Output (DatasetC)
CustomerID    HouseholdID   EmailAddress ... DatasetBHouseholdID
1001          100001        joe@aol.com       100001
1002          100002        john@gmail.com    .
2003          100003        sally@comcast.net 100003
...
```

I tried to do this:

```
data data.datasetc;
merge data.dataseta data.datasetb (RENAME=(householdID=datasetbhouseholdID));
by householdid;
run;
```

But that resulted in an error of course (BY variable householdID is not on input dataset data.datasetb).

I think the best course of action is to make DatasetB look like this:

```
DatasetB:
HouseholdID     DatasetBHouseholdID
100003            100003
100001            100001
```

But how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `IN=` dataset option.

```
data data.datasetc;
  merge data.dataseta data.datasetb (in=inB);
  by householdid;
  if inB then datasetbhouseholdID=householdID;
run;
```